# My email and password not going to firebase and im getting so much errors

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My email an password are jot going yo my furebasr app and my console is full of errors and I'm not even getting any Alert and Laos I have enabled the email and password in firebase I wanna save the email and password to firebase
And my console you can see has many errors pls help I am a beginner and I don't know so much

HTML

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>َAnimated Login Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.0/firebase.js"></script>

      <script src="function.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<form class="box" id="registrationform" method="post">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Email" Id="email">
  <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Password" Id="password">
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Login" onclick="signup()" sendMessage()>
</form>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.0/firebase.js"></script>

      <script src="function.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
//api details
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//Reference for form collection(3)
let formMessage = firebase.database().ref('register');

//listen for submit event//(1)
document
  .getElementById('registrationform')
  .addEventListener('submit', formSubmit);

//Submit form(1.2)
function formSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Get Values from the DOM
  let email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
  let password =document.querySelector('#password').value;

  //send message values
  sendMessage(email, password);

  //Show Alert Message(5)
  document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'block';

  //Hide Alert Message After Seven Seconds(6)
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'none';
  }, 7000);

  //Form Reset After Submission(7)
  document.getElementById('registrationform').reset();
}

//Send Message to Firebase(4)

function sendMessage(email, password) {
  let newFormMessage = formMessage.push();
  newFormMessage.set({
    email: email,
    password: password,
  });
}
```

I'm sharing my firebase app information because I'm jut testing I will gonna change

Answer (score 0):

My console

```
Console:
```

It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-.js
"
"
It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-.js
"
"
It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-.js
"
"
It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-.js
"
Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined
at https://cdpn.io/cp/internal/boomboom/pen.js?key=pen.js-71811b44-6916-8669-9ac6-a7c36bc1149d:11
"
It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-.js
"
"
It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-.js
"
Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined
at https://cdpn.io/cp/internal/boomboom/pen.js?key=pen.js-cb91a50a-44eb-6129-c1b9-cb282c9ac21b:11